# Request focus on expanding android searchview v7

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview

If I click the search icon on android app I want to auto focus the EditText of the searchview.

If I click on the search icon it expands the searchview (support.v7) and opens the soft input keyboard. But the cursor isn't set to the EditText so if I type something nothing is happening until I click on the EditText manually.

How can I set the focus to the EditText after clicking the search icon?

I tested searchview.setFocusable(true); but it isn't working ...

(tested on Galaxy Tab with Android 5 and Galaxy S6 with Android 5)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brandon!

Whole solution:

```
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchView.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try `searchview.requestFocus()`

Right now since you're only using setFocusable(true), you're basically just telling the device that your searchview *can* focus, not actually focusing on it.